# openGLES different behavior on different devices

Tags: android

I have some strange  behavior issues on texture-mapping with OpenGL ES 1.1

1)This is the right picture (Samsung Galaxy S):

[image]

2)This an wrong picture (HTC Magic):
[image]

3)This is another wrong picture (Ideos):

[image]

I am very disappointed for that, could someone help me?
I have mapped a texture in a  Sphere using OpenGL ES 1.1, the OpenGL need version is write in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

In the 2th case I can read a lot of this message:

**E/libEGL  ( 2372): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API**

I configured the checkError flag in OpenGLViewRender, but I cannot see the OpenGL call which 
cause this message.

Thanks a lot in advance.

pedr0

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the fact that not all devices support OpenGL 1.1, there are quite a few that only support 1.0

So if you are using extensions that don't exist in the current OpenGL implementation, you will end up getting this error.

To deal with this, you should check if the extension is available on the device and act accordingly. For more info on this, [check this page](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=21)

Comment: But I added this line for exclude this situation: <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" android:required="true" ></uses-feature>

Comment: How can I check the OpenGL extension inside an class which implements the  Renderer Interface?

Comment: The Renderer methods will receive an openGL context which you can use to get the extensions using gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);